# MDIChild to minimize not activated properly

Tags: delphi

Hello and thanks as always,
 I have a problem to minimize a MDIChild form in an MDI application MDIChild simple
 when I call the child form appears active and downplay it, but when I open more forms and I minimize, these are not active, always active appears to minimize the first form, I realized that the message WM_MDIACTIVATE not work, maybe I should overwrite any procedure window?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean when you minimize another child, the previously minimized child restores? Can you duplicate the behavior in a simplified project?

Comment: I think he means that when he minimizes a child window, instead of that child's caption appearing active as normal, the caption of a previous minimized child appears active instead.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: @Remy - I believe that's the proper behavior. A minimized window should deactivate, that's only possible by activating the next window in the chain.

Comment: So @Remy was right.   User - as I commented, that's normal behavior. Don't get your reference from new office applications etc., they don't use the MDI framework.

Comment: There must always be an active MDI child window. Minimizing a child window re-activates the previously active child.

Comment: thanks..I'm using xe2 update 4

Comment: exactly..The First child window minimized is always active, instead the last window minimized.. sorry my english

Comment: This is simply how MDI works, and always has (I reproduced the same behavior in BCB6). Is it really a problem?