# Delphi minimize all MDI children

Tags: delphi, mdi, mdichild

I have trouble in minimizing all my MDIChildren and came across [MDIChild to minimize not activated properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504456/mdichild-to-minimize-not-activated-properly)

My code to minimize all my children is:

```
procedure TMainWindow.MinimizeAll1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to MDIChildCount - 1 do begin
    MDIChildren[i].WindowState := wsMinimized;
    //ShowWindow(MDIChildren[i].Handle, SW_MINIMIZE)
  end;
end;
```

I tried both methods (SW_MINIMIZE and wsMinimized) but for some reason one last MDI children form gets NOT minimized. However if you try to minimize all the children again, it works. The minimize all works in the MDIAPP example from Delphi XE.
How do I properly minimize all MDI Children in 1 routine?

Comment: Just reverse your loop and done.

Comment: @user539484 I suspect that works also. But if it does it relies heavily on implementation details. Can you prove that it works? So I would strongly advise that your proposal is not used. You don't need to think about implementation details if you take a non-mutating copy of the list of children first, and then walk over that non-mutating list.

Comment: The reverse loop is actually not bad at all. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss State a proof as to why the reverse loop works. Even if you can, that proof will depend on the private unpublished details of the Windows MDI implementation.

Comment: @David Heffernan, yes I can, and you can either. Your answer why forward loop fails, same applies to *why reverse succeeds*.

Comment: @user So let's see the proof then. I bet that it depends on implementation detail.

Comment: @David Heffernan, stakes? ;-)

Comment: @user539484 I don't understand why you are being cryptic. I don't understand that comment, or the latest one to my answer.

Comment: @David Heffernan, bets. Wager. Interest. Personally, I do not understand why you requesting a proof for most simple and obvious solution, which too short even for an answer.

Comment: @user So, what is it. Just sketch it in a comment.

Comment: @David Heffernan, I knew you are as confident of your point :-) You can try to prove otherwise if you want to move away from the idle chat.

Comment: @user539484 Your proposed solution relies on the implementation of `TCustomForm.SetFocusedControl`. I prefer not to rely on such details. The issue is a little similar to the standard trick of iterating over a collection from last to first when one is deleting items from the collection. For some reason I'm comfortable doing that, but not with your trick.

Comment: @David Heffernan, that's not quite correct. But anyways, I found an a case where "snapshot" approach works better than "live" loop (Delphi's standard actions affected too, I never liked them)

Comment: @user539484 What's not quite correct, and why not? Or is it too obvious for you to explain?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, no, but its too late for extended discussions in comments ;) Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Uh all you guys, whats wrong with the `TWindowMinimizeAll` standard action? (Which by the way is implemented using a reverse loop, even has a comment that it needs to be done backwards.)

Comment: @MarjanVenema Standard actions are too weird for me!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, I understand the sentiment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimizing an MDI child window changes the order in which the forms appear in `MDIChildren[]`. This indexed property always returns the active MDI child in `MDIChildren[0]`. So, the cleanest way to do what you want is to take a copy of all the forms first, and then start minimizing.

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Forms: array of TForm;
....
SetLength(Forms, MDIChildCount);
for i := 0 to high(Forms) do
  Forms[i] := MDIChildren[i];
for i := 0 to high(Forms) do
  Forms[i].WindowState := wsMinimized;
```

Comment: This works but what if a MDIChild doesn't exist anymore, while your minimizing it?

Comment: Ask yourself that same question about your original loop? If you believe that a child form can die during execution of the code in this answer, then it can die during execution of the code in your question. But in fact it's not possible for an MDI child to be closed in the code above. You'd need to add a call to `ProcessMessages` to let that happen, and you aren't going to do that I hope!

Comment: Yep, you're right. I've tested the same with `ShowWindow (Handle, SW_RESTORE);` and the reverse loop didn't work out. In a nutshell : This is better and safer. Thank you :)

Comment: I'd guess that you'd need to go forwards when restoring, and backwards when minimizing. But it's just not worth trying to analyse all that. Play it safe.

Comment: @Benjamin Weiss, the following two statements illustrates a such a *safety*: `A := 0; if A <> 0 then Error;`